# How to create an endless picture-show without marquee?

Tags: javascript, marquee

I wrote a module for Joomla! 1.5 which shows the pictures (banners) with the most clicks. Now I want to show this list scrolling on the home-site. With "marquee" there is a break after the last picture.
I've found an advice which said I'll have to create a div-container with overflow: hidden and a second div with javascripte which changes the positions of the pictures.
Can anyone help me to write this code, because I don't get javascripte?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of free ones you can get that are already written for you.

Try one of these jquery scripts to do what you are looking for...

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/48

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement such feature is looking to this great JQuery Video tutorial and you will have a great product :)

URL: [JQuery Spy effect](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/simple-jquery-spy-effect/)

MOV: [Jquery Spy effect](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/media/simple-spy.mov)

Hope that is exactly what you are looking for.