# How to generate an animated scrolling image effect

Tags: javascript, html

I am using The following snippet in order to create a scrolling textbox:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #scroll {
      position: absolute;
      white-space: nowrap;
      top: 0px;
      left: 200px;
    }
    #oScroll {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function scroll(oid, iid) {
      this.oCont = document.getElementById(oid)
      this.ele = document.getElementById(iid)
      this.width = this.ele.clientWidth;
      this.n = this.oCont.clientWidth;
      this.move = function() {
        this.ele.style.left = this.n + "px"
        this.n--
          if (this.n < (-this.width)) {
            this.n = this.oCont.clientWidth
          }
      }
    }
    var vScroll

    function setup() {
      vScroll = new scroll("oScroll", "scroll");
      setInterval("vScroll.move()", 20)
    }
    onload = function() {
      setup()
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="oScroll">
    <div id="scroll">This is the scrolling text</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

however, I am looking to create a 'scrolling' image, and whenever I try to create an `<img>` tag within the 'This is the scrolling text' div, it doesn't show up on the page (at all).

I'm pretty new to javascript (ok, a complete novice) and would appreciate if anyone could inform me of a way of adding this image to this effect:

[image: Lorry]

I have been unable to find a way of creating something like this, other than creating my own gif image in photoshop/etc.

**EDIT**
I tried using a marqee, however:

[image: Using a Marquee]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an endless picture-show without marquee?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415821/how-to-create-an-endless-picture-show-without-marquee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an image that is 128px high into your div, you also need to change the height of the containing element from 20px to 128px.

Here's your code working:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #scroll {
      position: absolute;
      white-space: nowrap;
      top: 0px;
      left: 200px;
    }
    #oScroll {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 128px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function scroll(oid, iid) {
      this.oCont = document.getElementById(oid)
      this.ele = document.getElementById(iid)
      this.width = this.ele.clientWidth;
      this.n = this.oCont.clientWidth;
      this.move = function() {
        this.ele.style.left = this.n + "px"
        this.n--
          if (this.n < (-this.width)) {
            this.n = this.oCont.clientWidth
          }
      }
    }
    var vScroll

    function setup() {
      vScroll = new scroll("oScroll", "scroll");
      setInterval("vScroll.move()", 20)
    }
    onload = function() {
      setup()
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="oScroll">
    <img id="scroll" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8i8o.png' />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you possibly advise on an alternative? but feeling quite silly now that i see it was so simple

Comment: What do you need in an alternative solution that you can't do with this?

Comment: something that's actually 'clean'. I'm almost positive there's a better way of writing something like this (since i'm using this, everyone else must be using something different/better). Since this code was generated for using text quite some time ago, I would think there's a better/more efficient solution out there now :P

Comment: If you include [jQuery](http://jquery.com) there are plenty of plugins to choose from. You could always post this code to codereview.stackexchange.com to get some advice on cleaning this up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your existing code just alter the height of `#oScroll` in the CSS

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #scroll {
      position: absolute;
      white-space: nowrap;
      top: 0px;
      left: 200px;
    }
    #oScroll {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function scroll(oid, iid) {
      this.oCont = document.getElementById(oid)
      this.ele = document.getElementById(iid)
      this.width = this.ele.clientWidth;
      this.n = this.oCont.clientWidth;
      this.move = function() {
        this.ele.style.left = this.n + "px"
        this.n--
          if (this.n < (-this.width)) {
            this.n = this.oCont.clientWidth
          }
      }
    }
    var vScroll

    function setup() {
      vScroll = new scroll("oScroll", "scroll");
      setInterval("vScroll.move()", 20)
    }
    onload = function() {
      setup()
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="oScroll">
    <div id="scroll"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8i8o.png" /></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you possibly advise on an alternative? but feeling quite silly now that i see it was so simple